# iTextSharp | Embed xlsx file with export button in PDF in C#

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I want to attachment excel file in PDF with click_button, on click event it generate excel that contain PDF data. 
Attaching a code that I'm using for this process, due to lack in knowledge of iTextSharp was not able to embed the file. I'm not using any kind of web service. Please help me out. 
Thanks in Advance.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
    PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(stamper.Writer, null, "test.xlxs", null);
    stamper.AddFileAttachment("Some Test File",fs);
    stamper.Close();
```

Comment: "test.xlxs" shouldn't be this ".xlsx" ?

Comment: Plus tell me FileEmbedded contain parameter of filepath and byte [] file store, I pass null in both of them, passing null in file path due to filestream as it create the file and don't close it. That's filepath parameter given exception of file being use by other process. what you say how to control this exception

Comment: it should be "test.xlsx" I've correct my mistake